# Do people even use the Android Stack Exchange? The difference of SO and Android Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, specific-site

There is an [Android Stack Exchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/), but almost all serious Android answers are answered on [Stack Overflow](//www.stackoverflow.com) (Even multiple times because people are too lazy to search first).

Why not combine the two?

Comment: @mikaveli, I think this would fit better on meta apart from the fact that the people that need to read it are only on Stackoverflow rather than meta.     So I think it on balance it should stray here

Comment: @Ian It's not a programming question, it's a site discussion.

Comment: Confused why all the downvotes... This was moved and was a perfectly valid question.

Comment: This is now marked as a duplicate although the 'duplicate' was asked more than a year later than this question... hmmmm.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe so. StackOverflow is for more of Android related development Q&A, whereas Android StackExchange deals with non-development Android Q&A as well (like troubleshooting, etc.)

Comment: I was getting that impression but it is not really specified anywhere like that. Thanks for the feedback though.

Comment: No problem. For the record, even I don't visit the Android StackExchange page anymore. :-)

Comment: Exactly the reason behind my question... Who does and why not combine the two? It would also help people have less fragmented reputations and would show their expertise in one location.

Comment: @trgraglia Just like Apple **users** can ask all their questions on the Apple Stackexchange site, Android **users** can ask questions on Android Enthusiasts. The intended audience for both these sites is **all people that use** that particular system, whether they are programmers or not. Stackoverflow is for all programming questions. If an Android **usage** question is asked on SO, then it should be moved to the Android Enthusiasts site (this happens regularly).

Comment: Android - Stack Exchange is not for programming questions. Please ask your developer questions on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 19):

To quote  the [faq](https://android.stackexchange.com/faq) of android.stackexchange.

> Android - Stack Exchange is for enthusiasts, power users, and regular people too using the Android operating system. 
>   Android - Stack Exchange is **not** for programming questions. Please ask your developer questions on StackOverflow.